# How to clean text from .pdf artifacts?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am replacing placeholders in .pdf file like mentioned in itext7 doc

```
 PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getFirstPage();
    PdfDictionary dict = page.getPdfObject();

    PdfObject object = dict.get(PdfName.Contents);
    if (object instanceof PdfStream) {
        PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) object;
        byte[] data = stream.getBytes();
        String replacedData = new String(data).replace("{#Address_line1}", "Saint-Petersburg");
        stream.setData(replacedData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    pdfDoc.close()
```

My .pdf file is a little bit more complicated, so my `{#Address_line1}` placeholder looks like `({#)4(Add)-4(ress)-17(_)6(L)-6(i)3(n)-8(e1)4(})`

Are there any tools to clean up my placeholder, so that `({#)4(Add)-4(ress)-17(_)6(L)-6(i)3(n)-8(e1)4(})` will turn into `{#Address_line1}` ? I can write it myself, but maybe there are some ready solutions

Comment: There likely won't be such tools because what they would do pdf-wise is worsening the typesetting - those numbers in-between the partial strings implement kerning here. Furthermore, the case you show is not the worst case for you. The representation you show is still argument if a single text drawing instruction. But your placeholder may actually be drawn by more than one text drawing instruction, and in-between there may be other instructions still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way, need to implement my own solution.